# Disable Automatic Code Suggestion in Jupyter for magic and path

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jedi

Whenever I write a code in Jupyter Lab (or Notebook), it prompts annoying suggestions regarding magics and paths, even without pressing TAB. Example:

[image: annoying prompt]

This usually happens when the caret hits a closing bracket or parentheses. However
I don't have this problem in IPython.

I reverted the Jupyter user configuration changes to default, but the issue persists. Do you have a suggestion on how to solve this problem?
IMO reverting to a behavior when suggesting only on TAB hit will be the best. I wonder if it comes from Jupyter config or another LSP like Jedi (LSP is disabled in my experimental config)

### Details

Chrome
Ubuntu 22.04
jupyterlab 4.0.4

Comment: This is a feature. About your statement " I don't have this problem in IPython", do you mean when you are running IPython in a console/interpreter? That is because you cannot easily do such things in the console and that was why the GUI-based IPython notebook that involved into Jupyter was made. Back to making it in JupyterLab like you want, there are settings you can adjust. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jedi-autocompletion-disappears-after-typing-the-first-word/10586/2?u=fomightez). If that doesn't help, then maybe you can make your preferences and/or known or ask for more ...

Comment: <continued> guidance via the [link here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/enhanced-autocompletion-in-julia-r-and-python-lsp/7630/8?u=fomightez).

Comment: Thank you for your link, it appeared to me on one post that one of the sections Settings > Code completion > Enable auto-completion was ticked. I misunderstood this one and thought it was necessary to have the completion working. Setting to False solved my problem